# With a Broadcastreceiver I detect when na call has ended. After that I want to go to know activity, but the app stops. Why?

Tags: android, android-studio, broadcastreceiver, start-activity, startactivityforresult

I have this the following class to detect when a call ends etc.:

```
 public abstract class PhoneCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{
//The receiver will be recreated whenever android feels like it.  We need a static variable to remember data between instantiations

private static int lastState = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
private static Date callStartTime;
private static boolean isIncoming;
private static String savedNumber;  //because the passed incoming is only valid in ringing


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {




    //We listen to two intents.  The new outgoing call only tells us of an outgoing call.  We use it to get the number.
    if (intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL")) {
        savedNumber = intent.getExtras().getString("android.intent.extra.PHONE_NUMBER");
    }
    else{
        String stateStr = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE);
        String number = intent.getExtras().getString(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_INCOMING_NUMBER);
        int state = 0;
        if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_IDLE)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_OFFHOOK)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK;
        }
        else if(stateStr.equals(TelephonyManager.EXTRA_STATE_RINGING)){
            state = TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING;
        }


        onCallStateChanged(context, state, number);
    }
}

//Derived classes should override these to respond to specific events of interest
protected abstract void onIncomingCallReceived(Context ctx, String number, Date start);
protected abstract void onIncomingCallAnswered(Context ctx, String number, Date start);
protected abstract void onIncomingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end);

protected abstract void onOutgoingCallStarted(Context ctx, String number, Date start);
protected abstract void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end);

protected abstract void onMissedCall(Context ctx, String number, Date start);

//Deals with actual events

//Incoming call-  goes from IDLE to RINGING when it rings, to OFFHOOK when it's answered, to IDLE when its hung up
//Outgoing call-  goes from IDLE to OFFHOOK when it dials out, to IDLE when hung up
public void onCallStateChanged(Context context, int state, String number) {
    if(lastState == state){
        //No change, debounce extras
        return;
    }
    switch (state) {
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
            isIncoming = true;
            callStartTime = new Date();
            savedNumber = number;
            onIncomingCallReceived(context, number, callStartTime);
            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
            //Transition of ringing->offhook are pickups of incoming calls.  Nothing done on them
            if(lastState != TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                isIncoming = false;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onOutgoingCallStarted(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }
            else
            {
                isIncoming = true;
                callStartTime = new Date();
                onIncomingCallAnswered(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }

            break;
        case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
            //Went to idle-  this is the end of a call.  What type depends on previous state(s)
            if(lastState == TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING){
                //Ring but no pickup-  a miss
                onMissedCall(context, savedNumber, callStartTime);
            }
            else if(isIncoming){
                onIncomingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            }
            else{
                onOutgoingCallEnded(context, savedNumber, callStartTime, new Date());
            }
            break;
    }
    lastState = state;
}


}
```

With the following class I determine what should happen in the different scenarios:

```
 Public class CallReceiver extends PhoneCallReceiver {

...
...
...
@Override
protected void onOutgoingCallEnded(Context ctx, String number, Date start, Date end) { 

Context mContext =ctx;
    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Outgoing call ended", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

...
...
...
```

}

When a call ended I also want to go another activity. I checked a lot if question and answers here on Stack Overflow, I tried a lot of things out, but nothing worked.

I tried that I put those lines inside the onOutgoingCallEnded method:

```
  Intent i = new Intent();
i.setClassName("com.test", "com.test.NewActivity");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
ctx.startActivity(i);
```

and I also tried this, also putting it in the onOutgoingCallEnded method:

```
Intent i = new Intent(ctx,NewActivity.class);
ctx.startActivity(i);
```

Everytime, when a call ended instead of going into a new activity, my app just stopped.

Comment: Does it crash? If so post the logcat!

Comment: hey @OBX , this is the error level logcat: https://codeshare.io/ampmBW